# Google map: android.os.DeadObjectException - crash application

Tags: android, google-maps

Android Studio 3.1, Android 6.0
When I try to open tab with map in my application I get error:

```
06-26 19:22:24.541 D/audio_hw_primary(  199): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: audio-record
06-26 19:22:24.626 I/MicroDetectionWorker(16985): onReady
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778): Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778): android.os.DeadObjectException
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:286)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-26 19:22:24.887 W/WindowAnimator(  778):     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
06-26 19:22:24.908 W/top     ( 8226): type=1400 audit(0.0:166597433): avc: denied { search } for name="1" dev="proc" ino=5716 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

As result my application is crash.
But when I start my application on Android 4.4 it's success show tab with map.